# Persistent atop across reboots

Tags: command-line, monitoring, administration, atop

[`atop` shows total CPU time since the last reboot](https://superuser.com/q/1816687). How can I have it persist across reboots?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted: https://superuser.com/questions/1816687/persistent-atop-display

Comment: @RomeoNinov they are not duplicates. This one is to have it accumulate the stats across reboots, the one you linked is for showing the system stats after the default timeout of 10 seconds (it switches to stats for a 10 second window, not since boot).

Answer (score 1):

That's not a feature atop (or any other process monitor I'm aware of) has.

It's free and open source, so feel free to add your own functionality:

*Something* would have to save the time to permanent storage shortly before poweroff. So, you'd need to write a program to query the elapsed CPU time from the kernel, and write it to a file. You then would add that as a service to the systemd shutdown target.

You'd then need to modify `atop` to read that file, and add its content to the CPU time it reads from the kernel.

All in all, this seems a feature that's probably not something you very commonly see people want – if you're into counting CPU times of machines across many reboots, chances are you're someone running VMs and actually care about these, and then you'd query that as the host from the supervisor, not from the guests.

Comment: Does process accounting with [`sa`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sa) from `psacct` package not do this? I could not get it to work monotonously increasing.